# MongoDB update query is failing silently

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an app using Mongoid on top of MongoDB and an update is failing silently.

The code looks like this:

```
# Are we getting a new attribute? Yes we are!
p "attr first name = #{@attributes['first_name']}"

if user.update_attributes!(@attributes)
   u = User.find(params[:id]).to_json
end
```

No exception is thrown in this code.  So I looked at my MongoDB log and constructed this query based on what mongo is trying to do:

```
db.users.update({ "_id": "4d5561276ce886c496000001" }, { $set: { "first_name": "Erinamodobo" } }, false);
```

Now this does not cause any exceptions but when I grab the record that was supposed to be updated with this query:

```
db.users.find({"email":"escharling@somecompany.com"})
```

I see that the "first_name" attribute has not been updated.

Any idea why this could be happening?  Sounds like something stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Mongoid to the latest rc.7 fixed this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what

```
user.update_attributes!(@attributes)
```

is actually doing. This could be an issue with Mongoid. When you configure Mongoid, you can set up a logger. There you should be able to see what the driver is writing to MongoDB, and that should help answer your question. The next best thing is to post your code to the Mongoid mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid) where people who work with Mongoid all the time will probably know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "safe mode" on your operations.

Comment: i don't know who on earth gave this a vote down but i'm voting it up.

Comment: this is the really only first step you can take. safe mode requires that the mongodb server returns a status and blocks while waiting. this ensures you're not grabbing the value before mongo has a chance to update it.